# React Multiple Higher-Order Components without redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hoc

By the function name I'm sure you can understand the scenario of it just wanting to add some global components.

```
export default withLoading(withSnackbar(GlobalDropZone));
```

My question was exactly the same as [React Multiple Higher-Order Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606846/react-multiple-higher-order-components) , but it seems it didn't get an accurate answer. I browsed through [How do you combine/compose multiple Higher Order Components (react.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094580/how-do-you-combine-compose-multiple-higher-order-components-react-js) as well. It seems the existing approach is to use a third party plugin such as REDUX.
But I'm wondering if my code will create performance issues? Or is there a more elegant way to write it?

Comment: Generally, just the input: The ecosystem has moved from HOCs a lot and they are almost never used nowadays, except when working with legacy class components. If you knew that, fine, but if not I wanted to make you aware :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754560/how-to-implement-material-ui-snackbar-as-a-global-function I really don't know much because I am a learner and not a professional programmer. And with this I achieved the functionality I wanted, the problem came to me when I was making the second feature.

Comment: It's not bad knowing about the existance of HOCs, but nowadays something like that would probably be done with a custom hook. I'd encourage you to look into those things a little more.

Comment: I really appreciate @phry your guidance. hook does totally solve my problem: "performance concerns and global reuse". I changed my HOC code to HOOK rules and changed the function to USEEFFECT and it is now working well for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm wondering if my code will create performance issues?

The only performance difference will be the fact, that `GlobalDropZone`  will *re-render* if props passed by `withLoading` or `withSnackbar` will change (it depends if your `GlobalDropZone`  is a `PureComponent` or a `FC` (with `memo` or not).

> Or is there a more elegant way to write it?

You could use `compose` function from e.g. `lodash` to make it a bit more cleaner.

```
export default compose(withLoading, withSnackbar)(GlobalDropZone);
```

Comment: GlobalDropZone  is also a taking component, simple upload file drag and drop function, not using memo.

Comment: Is this lodash? https://github.com/lodash/lodash , I did not find that he has the compose function

Comment: @HappyKoala Just import it - `import { compose } from 'lodash/fp';`